# Empty data in rows after using Dapper QueryAsync in Dot Net Core

Tags: .net-core, dapper

I created a DataAccessLibrary Class Library to map my database and I am able to get the correct amount of rows for the query, but each column value is null. I am not sure why QueryAsync would return rows, but not the data within the rows.

```
    public async Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string sql, U parameters)
    {
        string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName);

        using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            try
            {
                var data = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sql, parameters);

                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }

                return data.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

[count of items in data list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BkAL.png)

[Quickwatch of item[0] showing all null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7WHR.png)

Answer (score 1):

Found out the problem. The property names in my class did not match the column names in the table. They MUST be exactly the same in order to be stored into a list.